# New LCD has different pixel layout, need more efficient method to translate array buffer (working method is too slow)

Tags: c, arrays, bit-manipulation, mathematical-optimization

Thanks in advance for any help anyone can provide!

Here is my issue: I am replacing an obsolete LCD. Both LCDs, new and old, are 240 wide by 128 tall pixels, but have different pixel arrangements.
I have written code to translate the Screen array from the OLD to the NEW format, but it is too slow. I am hoping someone better at bit manipulation that me can come up with a better method. Below is an arrangement as arrows that represent a byte of 8 pixels and what their orientation is on the LCD.

Basically the old LCD is arranged in 8 pixel bytes in horizontal slices that increment horizontally and wrap around then increment vertically.
The new LCD is arranged in 8 pixel bytes in vertical slices that increment horizontally and wrap around then increment vertically.

I am trying to visualize both arrangements with arrows representing the 8 pixel bytes as vertical or horizontal arrows pointing in the direction the bits increment. Each arrow in both representations is one byte or 8 pixels.

Here is the old LCD’s arrangement: 30 bytes by 128 bytes for 30,720 bits or pixels
240 bits horizontal is 30 bytes
128 bytes vertical
[Old LCD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qroq2.png)

Here is the new LCD’s arrangement: 240 bytes by 16 bytes for 30,720 bits or pixels
128 bits vertical in 16 bytes
240 bytes horizontal
[New LCD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VnsiP.png)

Below is my translation code that WORKS, but is too slow. It increments through the bytes of the new arrangement, finding where each bit for each byte from the old arrangement came from. Too slow and tedious, lagging the system, there must be a better way! I tried changing all function calls to inline code with no improvement.

```
#define DISPLAY_BUFFER_SIZE     3840            // buffer size in *bytes*
#define HORIZONTAL_PIX    240
#define VERTICAL_ROWS    16
#define VERTICAL_PIX    128
#define HORIZONTAL_COL    30
#define BITS_IN_BYTE    8

UBYTE isBitSet(UBYTE* arr, USHORT bit)
{
    USHORT index = bit / 8;  // Get the index of the array for byte with this bit
    USHORT bitPosition = 7-(bit % 8);  // Position of this bit a byte   Every byte on the OLD LCD was bit swapped from MSB to LSB so annoyingly this is reversed here
   return (arr[index] >> bitPosition & 1) == 1;
}


// main code inside another function

    for (i=0; i<DISPLAY_BUFFER_SIZE; i++)
    {
        newbyte_pos = i % HORIZONTAL_PIX;  // Value is 0 to 29.     30 = 240col / 8bits
        newbyte_offset = i / HORIZONTAL_PIX;    // Value is 0 to 127
        new_display_byte = 0x00;

        // Bit 0
        oldbit_num = (newbyte_offset * 1920) + (240 * 0) + newbyte_pos;
        if (isBitSet(buffer_pointer, oldbit_num))
            new_display_byte |= 0x01;
        // Bit 1
        oldbit_num = (newbyte_offset * 1920) + (240 * 1) + newbyte_pos;
        if (isBitSet(buffer_pointer, oldbit_num))
            new_display_byte |= 0x02;
        // Bit 2
        oldbit_num = (newbyte_offset * 1920) + (240 * 2) + newbyte_pos;
        if (isBitSet(buffer_pointer, oldbit_num))
            new_display_byte |= 0x04;
        // Bit 3
        oldbit_num = (newbyte_offset * 1920) + (240 * 3) + newbyte_pos;
        if (isBitSet(buffer_pointer, oldbit_num))
            new_display_byte |= 0x08;
        // Bit 4
        oldbit_num = (newbyte_offset * 1920) + (240 * 4) + newbyte_pos;
        if (isBitSet(buffer_pointer, oldbit_num))
            new_display_byte |= 0x10;
        // Bit 5
        oldbit_num = (newbyte_offset * 1920) + (240 * 5) + newbyte_pos;
        if (isBitSet(buffer_pointer, oldbit_num))
            new_display_byte |= 0x20;
        // Bit 6
        oldbit_num = (newbyte_offset * 1920) + (240 * 6) + newbyte_pos;
        if (isBitSet(buffer_pointer, oldbit_num))
            new_display_byte |= 0x40;
        // Bit 7
        oldbit_num = (newbyte_offset * 1920) + (240 * 7) + newbyte_pos;
        if (isBitSet(buffer_pointer, oldbit_num))
            new_display_byte |= 0x80;

        new_display_buf[i] = new_display_byte;
    }
 }
```

Comment: Why do you tag two languages? You're only writing in one of them.

Comment: Try *inlining* or pasting your `isBitSet` code in the locations.    Changing execution paths slows down the processor.

Comment: compiler might already be doing this, but there's no need to calculate `newbyte_offset * 1920` 8 times.. just do that once. Maybe you could pre-compute `240 * x` as well, then just add the right one.

Comment: Can you avoid the division by using shifting?  Division is another item that slows down execution.

Comment: Does the original code not have a single, or a few, functions that handles everything written to the display at pixel level? If not, have you mixed *form* with *function*? One solution, is to bite the bullet and rewrite those badly written parts of the program, rather than introduce a kludge which would make the program even harder to maintain.

Comment: Try coming up with a mathematical relationship between the old bits and the new bits.  All the comparisons are slowing down your program.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the new code based on the very helpful suggestion from Mark Ransom:

```
void transpose8x8bits(UBYTE * block, UBYTE * result)
{
    int bit;
    for (bit = 7; bit >= 0; bit--)
    {
        result[7-bit] = (((block[0] >> bit) & 1) << 0) |
                        (((block[30] >> bit) & 1) << 1) |
                        (((block[60] >> bit) & 1) << 2) |
                        (((block[90] >> bit) & 1) << 3) |
                        (((block[120] >> bit) & 1) << 4) |
                        (((block[150] >> bit) & 1) << 5) |
                        (((block[180] >> bit) & 1) << 6) |
                         (((block[210] >> bit) & 1) << 7);
    }
}

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // calling code

    buf_inx = 0;
    for (z=0; z<16; z++)  // 128 bits / 8 bit per byte = 16 bytes
    {
        for (i=0; i<30; i++)
        {
            transpose8x8bits((buffer_pointer+i+(z*240)), (new_display_buf+buf_inx));
            buf_inx += 8;
        }
    }
```

This gives at least an order of magnitude improvement which is completely workable for my task; no more excessive lagginess! Though I am open to further optimizations that anyone would suggest. I'm sure my implementation of Mark's idea is far from optimized. Thanks again Mark!

Comment: Ah, I see my mistake now - you need to traverse the entire line, not 8 pixels. I'm glad you figured it out! I'd change the name though, it's not a 8x8 transpose anymore.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a function that can transpose a block of 8x8 bits quickly, then you can run it on all 480 blocks in your display.

```
void transpose8x8bits(UBYTE * block, UBYTE * result)
{
    int bit;
    for (bit = 7; bit >= 0; bit--)
    {
        result[7-bit] = (((block[0] >> bit) & 1) << 7) |
                        (((block[1] >> bit) & 1) << 6) |
                        (((block[2] >> bit) & 1) << 5) |
                        (((block[3] >> bit) & 1) << 4) |
                        (((block[4] >> bit) & 1) << 3) |
                        (((block[5] >> bit) & 1) << 2) |
                        (((block[6] >> bit) & 1) << 1) |
                         ((block[7] >> bit) & 1);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Mark, this looks like exactly what I need. I will try it out and post back on the improvement.

Comment: I tried to Up vote your answer but it says my rep is too low for it to count.

Comment: @CharlesNuzum don't worry, it will work out in the end. You should eventually be able to hit the checkmark to show that this is the accepted answer, but I wouldn't do that until you *know* that it works well.

Comment: Hi Mark, I think you misunderstood the layout change a little, but no matter, a few changes to your suggestion, and it works and is MUCH faster. Here is how I used your code:

Comment: void transpose8x8bits(UBYTE * block, UBYTE * result)
{
    int bit;
    for (bit = 7; bit >= 0; bit--)
    {
        result[7-bit] = (((block[0] >> bit) & 1) << 0) |
                        (((block[30] >> bit) & 1) << 1) |
                        (((block[60] >> bit) & 1) << 2) |
                        (((block[90] >> bit) & 1) << 3) |
                        (((block[120] >> bit) & 1) << 4) |
                        (((block[150] >> bit) & 1) << 5) |
                        (((block[180] >> bit) & 1) << 6) |
                         (((block[210] >> bit) & 1) << 7);
 }
}

Comment: inx = 0;
  for (z=0; z<16; z++)  // 128 bits / 8 bit per byte = 16 bytes
  {
   for (i=0; i<30; i++)
   {
    transpose8x8bits((buffer_pointer+i+(z*240)), (new_display_buf+inx));
    inx += 8;
   }
  }